# Python pattern for keeping default arguments of subfunction

Tags: python, design-patterns, default-arguments

Suppose I have a function with a default argument and another function calling it.  I want to let the caller either override the default argument or keep it.  I've fallen into the following pattern.  Is this an antipattern, is this best practices, is there a better way?

```
def subfunc(x=10):
    # do something with x

def callingfunc(x=None):
    y= subfunc() if x is None else subfunc(x) # IS THIS AN ANTI PATTERN?
```

Comment: Please tell me if my answer reflects your intent. I am not absolutely sure of why you wrote the code that way.

Comment: No, not quite.  In your answer callingfun() will print none, but it should print 10, i.e. keep the default of subfunc.

Comment: Ok, I got confused :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often one uses optional varargs (`*args`) and/or (preferably imho) optional keyword args (`**kwargs`) for this. Supposing `callingfunc()` also takes some own param `y`:

```
def subfunc(x=10):
    """ Do something with x

    :param x: used to do something (default: 10)
    """
    print("subfunc({})".format(x))

def callfunc(y, **kwargs):
    """ Do something with `y` and calls `subfunc()`

    :param y: something to do something with
    :param kwargs: will be passed to `subfunc()` (cf `subfunc() doc)`
    """ 

    print("callfunc({})".format(y))
    subfunc(**kwargs)


callfunc(42)
callfunc(42, x="bar")
```

This let you easily know which are `callfunc()` own params and which are only for `subfunc()`, and makes life much easier than your solution if `subfunc()` has more than one param.

Comment: Right, this makes sense, but what about the case that call func already needs **kwargs for other reasons?  Either way you answered my question but I'm curious about this.

Comment: @moquant well then you're in trouble xD (and you possibly have a design issue too).

Comment: 'or you possible have a design issue', ok this gets to the heart of my question really.  If I'm running into trouble here then its possibly a design issue (and maybe I have fallen into a bad pattern).  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
   This answer always overrides `subfunc` `x` parameter, because
   there is no way for `subfunc` to be called without a defined
   `x` parameter.
   So it's not right.

I'm not fixing it because Bruno's answer is
   already a good one.

---

You can write it this way:

```
def subfunc(x=10):
    print(x)

def callingfunc(x=None):
    subfunc(x)

callingfunc()
callingfunc(20)
callingfunc(30)
```

It prints:

```
None
20
30
```

So you either pass a value that overrrides 10, or you don't, and override
10 with the `callingfunc` default value for x, in this case `None`.

Comment: The OP stated : "I want to let the caller either override the default argument or keep it". Your solution does not handle the second case.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I got it. I override or override in my answer.